# YouTube API Uploading Videos

Tags: video, file-upload, youtube, youtube-api

Basically once a person has recorded a video, I want the person to be able to upload it to a particular YouTube account. Now I know that you can upload a video but whilst that video is uploading, could you then upload another video? What I mean is if another video is being uploaded, does it stop the previous upload if it has not finished yet or will it just continue to upload both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, video uploads are async. You can upload many at once.